# Update resulting records with substring of found records

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( c.psosrc, 4, 2 ) as substr
    , c.psolink_id
FROM psolink_history as c
WHERE c.psosrc
IN ( 10015, 10016, 10017, 10018, 10019, 10020, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10025, 10026 )
```

I want to update `c.psosrc` with the result of SUBSTRING for the values found in `10015, 10016, 10017, 10018, 10019, 10020, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10025, 10026`

e.g. I want to update:

- 10015 with 15
- 10026 with 26
- ...

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This query will update the `psosrc` with the result of `SUBSTRING(...)`.

However `psosrc` seems to be an `int` value. Using `SUBSTRING` and implicit conversions to String does not seem right.

Given your sample, it seems that you only want to keep the last 2 digits from `psosrc`. If this is the case, Modulo should work:

```
SELECT psosrc % 100
FROM psolink_history as c
WHERE c.psosrc
IN ( 10015, 10016, 10017, 10018, 10019, 10020, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10025, 10026 )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0e51/2/0) shows both value (`SUBSTRING` and Modulo).

#### Update query:

```
UPDATE psolink_history
SET psosrc = SUBSTRING(psosrc, 4, 2)
WHERE psosrc
    IN ( 10015, 10016, 10017, 10018, 10019, 10020, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10025, 10026 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last 2 digit you can use [RIGHT(str,len)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_right) function:

```
UPDATE psolink_history
SET psosrc = RIGHT(psosrc, 2)
WHERE psosrc
IN ( 10015, 10016, 10017, 10018, 10019, 10020, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10025, 10026 )
```

You can test the output before the update with a simple query:

```
SELECT psosrc AS original, RIGHT(psosrc, 2) AS mod
FROM psolink_history
WHERE psosrc
IN ( 10015, 10016, 10017, 10018, 10019, 10020, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10025, 10026 )
```